# How to make select2 dropdown options transparent?

Tags: css

I am trying to make select2 dropdown menu transparent. I managed to change color with:

`.select2-results__option {
  background-color: green !important;
}`

[image]

but as soon as `background-color: transparent !important;` is set, the color is getting back to default white;

[image]

May someone tell where I am missing the point.

Comment: you must add a working example of what you have tried

Comment: Would you provide a working example of this problem, maybe a JS Fiddle or an example in the editor? Perhaps those elements _are_ becoming transparent, but the item behind them was white to start off with?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try opacity, I threw together a dropdown menu with `opacity:.5`, I did it in [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/6HOzi4iFYD) (online bootstrap editor)

CSS

```
.container{
  background-color:green;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    opacity:.5; 
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown clearfix">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried you solution, but still, seems that opacity is set on the white background, maybe because `select` is made with https://select2.org/ jquery plugin, dunno.